# Calculating size of circles on window resize

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, window-resize

In my demo that you can run below, I generate circles with random positions and sizes.

I set the page to reload when you resize the window, but this not what I want. *I would like to recalculate the size and the position of circles when the window is resized, without reloading the page*.

I tried a bunch of things, but I simply can’t get it to work. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

---

```js
// Draw circles

const list = (length, callback) =>
  Array.from(new Array(length), (hole, index) => callback(index))

const random = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min

const viewportWidth = Math.max(
  document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  window.innerWidth || 0
)

const viewportHeight = Math.max(
  document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  window.innerHeight || 0
)

const elements = list(48, () => {
  const circle = document.createElement("span")
  const minSize = Math.round((viewportWidth + viewportHeight) / 48)
  const maxSize = Math.round((viewportWidth + viewportHeight) / 24)
  const size = random(minSize, maxSize)
  Object.assign(circle.style, {
    width: `${size}px`,
    height: `${size}px`,
    left: `${random(0, 100)}%`,
    top: `${random(0, 100)}%`
  })
  return circle
})

document.body.append(...elements)

// Reload page on window resize

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  window.location.reload(true)
})
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden }

span {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5
}
```

Comment: Put your code for generating and "printing" the circles in a function and call this instead of reloading the page on `resize` o.O

Comment: @Andreas Could you please post the solution as an answer so I can upvote and accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to add it as answer yourself. Imho that's more a reason to close as to broad.

Comment: instead px, use vh or vw ov vmax or vmin units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead px, use vh or vw ov vmax or vmin units

some explanation here https://web-design-weekly.com/2014-11-18-viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

> **vw:** 1/100th viewport width
>
> **vh:** 1/100th viewport height
>
> **vmin:** 1/100th of the smallest side
>
> **vmax:** 1/100th of the largest side

```js
// Draw circles

const list = (length, callback) =>
  Array.from(new Array(length), (hole, index) => callback(index))

const random = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min

const viewportWidth = Math.max(
  document.documentElement.clientWidth,
  window.innerWidth || 0
)

const viewportHeight = Math.max(
  document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  window.innerHeight || 0
)

const elements = list(48, () => {
  const circle = document.createElement("span")
  const minSize = Math.round((viewportWidth + viewportHeight) / 150) // tune this to your needs
  const maxSize = Math.round((viewportWidth + viewportHeight) / 80)// tune this to your needs
  const size = random(minSize, maxSize)
  Object.assign(circle.style, {
    width: `${size}vmin`,// vmin used instead px , but vh,vw aand vmax is also avalaible
    height: `${size}vmin`,// vmin used instead px , but vh,vw aand vmax is also avalaible
    left: `${random(0, 100)}%`,
    top: `${random(0, 100)}%`
  })
  return circle
})

document.body.append(...elements)
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden }

span {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5
}
```

Comment: That’s a clever and a very simple solution. Thanks!